# Tikz modify part of polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw a deformed hexagon, defined by polar coordinates. I wish define a distance `\aI` and express the second polar coordinates using with this variable, but I get complying error.

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `$' or`$(' (in '($
>   (0.482962913').

My MnWE (Minimal not-Working Example):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,calc}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\newdimen\aI
\aI=1cm

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0]


  \begin{scope}[yshift=0cm]
        \draw[yshift=0cm] (37.5:($ (0.482962913)*(\aI) $)) --
        (90:($ (1.276316253*\aI) $ )) -- (142.5:($ (0.482962913*\aI) $ )) -- (232.5:($ (0.482962913*\aI) $ )) -- (270:($ (1.276316253*\aI) $ )) -- (307.5:($ (0.482962913*\aI) $ )) -- cycle ;
  \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Helps will be welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need these `$` signs or the extra `()` either.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=0]
\begin{scope}[yshift=0cm]
\draw[yshift=0cm] (37.5:0.482962913\aI) --
    (90:1.276316253\aI)    -- (142.5:0.482962913\aI) --
    (232.5:0.482962913\aI) -- (270:1.276316253\aI) -- 
    (307.5:0.482962913\aI) -- cycle ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```